# Issue when adding a new div to an already created flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a simple login page using HTML/CSS. I created a flexbox to have the box centered on the screen. I have the Username/password fields and login button positioned how I would like them. I just need to add a title for it but when I try to add a div to the container it gets rid of all the positioning for the other elements in the flex box.

Here is the login html page with the title div I want to add commented out to show that it works.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

#loginBox {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0px 3px 8px;
}

#usernameBox {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#passwordBox {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 44%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#loginButton {
  position: relative;
  left: 58%;
  top: 53%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 72, 1);
  color: white;
  border: .5px solid black;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="loginBox">
    <!-- <div id="title">Log in</div> -->
    <input id="usernameBox" placeholder="Username"></input>
    <input id="passwordBox" placeholder="Password"></input>
    <button id="loginButton" type="submit">Log in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like before adding the title div:

[image]

This is what happens after I uncomment the html code:

[image]

How to I add the title into the "loginBox" while keeping the same formatting of the Username/password fields and button?

Comment: The demo from your code - after switching `id` attributes to `class`, and updating the selectors - doesn't seem to reproduce the problem you describe: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4qe739yp/

Comment: `</input>` does not exist in HTML, remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you've added **fixed sizes** for the positions of your Inputs.

Try to use `flex` and add `margin-top` to the elements like this:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  
}

#loginBox {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0px 3px 8px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#usernameBox {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#passwordBox {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: large;
  border: 1px groove black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#loginButton {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 72, 
    1);
  color: white;
  border: .5px solid black;
  font-size: small;
  align-self: end;
margin-right: 35px;
}

#loginBox > *{
  margin-top:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="loginBox">
    <h1>Thisis the Header!</h1>
    <!-- <div id="title">Log in</div> -->
    <input id="usernameBox" placeholder="Username"></input>
    <input id="passwordBox" placeholder="Password"></input>
    <button id="loginButton" type="submit">Log in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```